# Angular js table with dynamic columns and values

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a data structure as follow;

```
[
  {
    "a1": 941,
    "b1": "abc",
    "c1": "aaa",
    "a2": 27103,
    "b2": "ttt",
    "c2": "zzz"
  },
  {
    "a1": 456,
    "b1": "xxx",
    "c1": "yyy",
    "a2": 7632,
    "b2": "mmm",
    "c2": "nnn"
  }
]
```

I use angular js table with dynamic column names which are different from keys in the structure. Since there are many of them, I do not want to write key names like;

```
 <table st-table="table_data_raw" style="" class="table table-striped forms-list-table">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="dateColumnName in dateColumnNames ">{{ dateColumnName }}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td>{{row.a1 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.b1 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.a2 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.b2 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.c2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

How can I get table values dynamically without specifying their names in that structure from "data"?

Comment: note: there is no guarantee on key sequence for javascript object

Answer (score 0):

Try using $index to refer to the ng-repeat item you wish to access (in your example it would be index 0 or 1). Here is code/fiddle (click items in the table to get their value dynamically):
https://jsfiddle.net/AdamKMorris/ox89o7L0/

using $Index:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td ng-click="chosenValueA1($index);">{{row.a1 }}</td>
            ...
  </tr>
```

Then the angularJs:

```
  $scope.chosenValueA1 = function(i)
  {
    $scope.myValue = $scope.data[i].a1;
  }
```

If you want to access a1,a2,b1,b2, etc. then you will need to nest ng-repeat and use $index for each to refer to the value.